# How do I count all values that satisfy X mod N=1 in the range [A,B]

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, divisor-counting-function

I want to count how many values of x in range [A,B] give remainder of 1 when divided by N.
Is there any formula I can apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find $X$ from $[A,B]$ such that
$$X\equiv1\quad(\text{mod }N)$$
which is the same as
$$X-1\equiv0\quad(\text{mod }N)$$
Now $X-1$ is from $[A{-}1,B{-}1]$, so you want to find the number of multiples of $N$ in that interval.

It's not hard to see there are $\left\lfloor\frac KN\right\rfloor+1$ multiples of $N$ in $[0,K]$ and $\left\lceil\frac KN\right\rceil$ in $[0,K)$. The interval $[A-1,B-1]$ can be written as $[0,B-1]$ without $[0,A-1)$, so the answer is
$$\left\lfloor\frac{B-1}N\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{A-1}N\right\rceil+1$$

The symbols $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ and $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ denote the [floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) respectively. Also note that I assume $A-1$ and $B-1$ to be positive, but the method still works if you consider $\left\lfloor\frac KN\right\rfloor+1$ and $\left\lceil\frac KN\right\rceil$ to mean the **signed** number of multiples of $N$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use this notation: $\lceil x\rceil$ is the least integer that is not lesser than $x$, and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer that is not greater than $x$.
For example, $\lceil 5.4 \rceil=6$ and $\lfloor 5.4 \rfloor=5$, and $\lceil 5\rceil=\lfloor 5\rfloor=5$.
It is also advsisable to take two negative examples: $\lceil -5.4\rceil=-5$, $\lfloor -5.4 \rfloor=-6$, $\lceil -5\rceil=\lfloor -5\rfloor=-5$

The first of these values is $Na+1$ for some integer $a$. Then, $Na+1\geq A$ and $Na+1-N<A$. That is,
$$A\leq Na+1 <A+N$$
Divide by $N$ to get:
$$\frac AN\leq a+\frac1N<\frac AN+1$$
that is,
$$\frac{A-1}N\leq a<\frac{A-1}N+1$$
In other words, 
$$a=\left\lceil\frac{A-1}N\right\rceil$$

Now, the last of the values that you want to count is $Nb+1$ for some integer $b$. Similarly, 
$$B-N<Nb+1\leq B$$
or
$$\frac {B-1}N-1<b\leq \frac{B-1}N$$
or equivalently,
$$b=\left\lfloor\frac{B-1}N\right\rfloor$$

Then, there are 
$$\left\lfloor\frac{B-1}N\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac{A-1}N\right\rceil+1$$
of these values.